# Error in export to excel in oracle forms11g

Tags: java, weblogic, oracleforms

I am using `oracle forms 11g`,`weblogic 10.3.6` and `java 1.7`

I have tested `webutil_demo`, that worked successfully.

After that, I have implement a oracle form for `export to excel` functionality using `webutil`.

This form worked fine on `server machine`.
but other than `server machine` it gives an following Error:

```
oracle.forms.webutil.ole.OleFunctions bean not found.
CLIENT_OLE2.create_obj will not work
```

Note : on `server machine`, `webutil_demo` also worked fine.

I dont understand why this error.So please help me for solve this problem.

Comment: Are you sure that oracle does find the right webutill.pll?

Comment: Yes,server machine it working fine!

Comment: Do you have Microsoft office installed on your server? Which version? It provides OLE container for export

Comment: Yes,listen on my server machine excel file generate successfully,other than server machine it get problem and other machine also have Microsoft office.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you have not imported webutil.pll and webutil.olb(do import "WEBUTILCONFIG" parameter and "WEBUTIL" Object group, webutil.pll and webutil.olb are available in Oracle installation directory say "C:\Oracle\Middleware\\forms") on your form.
  If you dont want OLE functionality on your form, in that case import the object group of the name "WEBUTIL_NO_OLE".